# Dynamically generate unique primary key for a column composition in a T-SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, composite-primary-key

Does anybody know if there's a way to generate a unique integer primary key in MS SQL Server / Transact SQL SELECT statement?

I've got the problem that I've got to merge 3 datatables programmatically by a composition of columns (like a composite primary key). The composition isn't the actual primary key though.

My tables look somewhat like this:

```
Table 1: Base Table which is needed to be filled: 
+----------+------+----------------+------------+----------+
|operatorid|opcode|bookkeeping_date|cash_amount |tip_amount|
+----------+------+----------------+------------+----------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.01.2018     |null        |null      |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+----------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.02.2018     |null        |null      |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+----------+
| 2        | 2    | 01.02.2018     |null        |null      |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+----------+

Table 2: Cash Data Table to be merged with base table
+----------+------+----------------+------------+
|operatorid|opcode|bookkeeping_date|cash_amount |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.01.2018     |2.50        |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.02.2018     |17.80       |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+
| 2        | 2    | 01.02.2018     |4.20        |
+----------+------+----------------+------------+

Table 3: Tip Data Table to be merged with base table: 
+----------+------+----------------+----------+
|operatorid|opcode|bookkeeping_date|tip_amount|
+----------+------+----------------+----------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.01.2018     |3.50      |
+----------+------+----------------+----------+
| 1        | 1    | 01.02.2018     |4.20      |
+----------+------+----------------+----------+
| 2        | 2    | 01.02.2018     |0.00      |
+----------+------+----------------+----------+
```

So simplified the goal is to fill "Table 1: Base Table" by merging the datatables. We already have a c# method to manage the merge by primary key after the datatables are selected.

My problem now is that I don't have a unique primary key but the composition of "operatorid" and "bookkeeping_date".

Is there a way I could modify my SELECT statements for each table to get a unique integer by hash or checksum or stuff like that?

Edit: The cash amount and the tip amount are summed up values in the table select statements with the aggregate SUM() being used.

Best regards

Epanalepsis

Comment: Have you looked at [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: you can get unique rows Id by combining, operatorid|opcode|bookkeeping_date

Comment: ROW_NUMBER isn't an option since the select statements must be grouped due to aggregate functions in the select statements. :/

Comment: Should have mentioned that tip and also cash amount are summed up.

Comment: What is the desired answer.  I don't think this is possible as a table has no natural order.

Comment: I kinda desire a solution lihe RealDealNeills but a little more consistent.

Comment: It looks like you believe a common bit of fake SQL Server lore - that PKs must be INTs. While an int is *usually* the most efficient way, PKs can indeed be composite. If date + operator is unique, then use that as your PK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that data can regularly change in these tables, and since historical records could always be introduced that throws off any ranking or row number functions, it'd probably be best to go a route that uses the operatorid and bookkeeping_date in tandem to create a unique key.

One simple approach would be to convert the date to an integer value, and append the operatorid to the end.

1/1/2018 becomes "43099". Operatorid 1 becomes of "1" at the end (or "01"/"001"/"0001" if these IDs have the chance of becoming larger integers).

```
select
convert(int, convert(varchar(6), convert(int, (convert(datetime,replace(bookkeeping_date,'.','-'),110)))) 
    + convert(varchar(2), operatorid)) as unique_id
from (select 1 as operatorid, 1 as opcode, '01.01.2018' as bookkeeping_date, 3.50 as tip_amount) tip
```

You'd have a few centuries before the date integers reach six digits and might cause some complications - but you could also convert the date integer to something with trailing zeroes as well to accommodate that if it's a concern.

Comment: That's an approach I considered aswell but I'm a little afraid about the uniqueness and the integer range. :/

Comment: If you use a bigint instead of an int, you would have many more values available. Also, an interesting coincidence - the date integer reaches six digits on this date (Oct 16th) in 2173. If your code should still be running after that, I recommend another approach.